# ES6 named imports

Tags: es6-modules

Just out of curiosity, and I'm sure I should've learned this somewhere along the way, but why do we use named imports in some situations opposed to default import?

ex:

```
import localName from 'src/my_lib';
import { name1, name2 } from 'src/my_lib';
```

Little background: I'm just dabbling with dev tools for hobbyist reasons.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only import the default export of the file with the first example. A file can however have multiple exports which are named in the file you import, named imports allows you to import as many exports from a file as you want.

Comment: you didn't answer the question